# How to create a reusable /common dialog component with usecontext react hook using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to create a reusable /common dialog component using usecontext react hook and typescript.

what i am trying to do?

I have to create a dialog that shows up on clicking add or click me buttons and closes on clicking hide button on the dialog. once dialog is closed it should not be opened for the session again on clicking add or click me buttons.

The code below works

Within helper.ts file

```
interface ContextProps {
    setDialogOpen?: (open: boolean) => void;   
}

export const DialogContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({});
```

within Main.tsx file i have

```
function MainComponent() {
    let [showDialog, setShowDialog] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <DialogContext.Provider
            value={{
                setDialogOpen: (open: boolean) => {
                    if (open) {
                        const sessionDialogClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('dialog');
                        if (sessionDialogClosed !== 'closed') {
                            setShowDialog(open);
                            sessionStorage.setItem('dialog', 'closed');
                        }
                    } else {
                        setShowDialog(open);
                    }
                },
            }}
        >
        {showDialog && <Dialog DialogContext={DialogContext}/>
            <Route 
                path="/items">
                <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route
                path="/id/item_id">
                <Books/>
            </Route>
        </DialogContext.Provider>
    )     
}
```

Withing home.tsx

```
function Home() {
    const dialogContext= React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (dialogContext && dialogContext.setDailogOpen) {
            dialogContext.setDialogOpen(true); 
        }
        return ( 
            <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
        )
}
```

Within books.tsx file

```
function Books({DialogContext} : Props) {
    const dialogContext= React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const handleClick = () {
        if(dialogContext && dialogContext.setDialogOpen) {
            dialogContext.setDialogOpen(true); 
        }
        return ( 
            <button onClick={handleClick()}>Click me</button>
        )    
    }
}
```

Within Dialog.tsx file

```
function Dialog() {
    const onHide = () => {
        if (dialogContext && dialogContext.setDialogOpen) {
            dialogContext.setDialogOpen(false);
        }
    }
    return(
        <div>
            //sometext
            <button onClick={onHide}> hide</button> 
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

I want to make this code look neat meaning i want to include the DialogContext withing Dialog.tsx file where the Dialog component itself is defined and use some hook to access this.

I am not sure how to do it. Learning react still a beginner. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: I think that it is not good idea. 

Read first.
- https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context
- https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0


1. use `children(React.ReactNode)`, do not insert container(content) DOM.
2. create component
3. create useEffect for common usage window event.
4. ...